# WinPhone8 WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using a WebBrowser component in an app to display some generated HTML on a page in an App. When I navigate back from the page there is a noticeable lag when the browser control disappears off the page and then about 1/2 second later the rest of the page disappears.

Having run Application Analysis on it, each time this happens the app responsiveness drops to zero and it appears to be doing a GC collection.

Is there anyway to avoid this lag when closing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Latency Modes` of the `Garbage Collector`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx

Hope it helps :)